# Ultrafilter on $\omega$ which satisfies $\sum_\limits{n\in U}a_n = \infty$ for any $U\in\mathcal{U}$ where $a_n$ is convergent

Tags: filters

The question is to show there is an infinite sequence of reals $\langle a_n\rangle$ with $\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=0$ and an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\omega$ such that $$\sum_\limits{n\in U}a_n = \infty$$ for any $U\in\mathcal{U}$.

Should I provide some tricky construction or show the sequence and the ultrafilter explicitly or...? I have absolutely no idea what to do, not even a single one. I don't know much about ultrafilters besides their definition, the notion of principal ultrafilters and some other less useful facts. But this problem here... I don't know. Could you give me a hint or tell where to start with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Let $a_n=\frac1{n+1}$ for $n\in\omega$. Let

$$\mathscr{I}=\left\{I\subseteq\omega:\sum_{n\in I}a_n<\infty\right\}\;.$$

Show that $\mathscr{I}$ is an ideal, and expand it to a maximal ideal.

Comment: I already accepted this answer, but now I'm wondering - how do we know that the expanded ideal preserves the condition given on the ideal we start with (namely that it corresponds to these elements in the sequence which give finite sums)? Because from what I understand we would like to say that the filter dual to this expanded ideal is an ultrafilter that fits the description of the problem.

Comment: @Jules: The maximal ideal contains $\mathscr{I}$, so it contains all of the ‘bad’ subsets of $\omega$, and the complementary ultrafilter therefore contains only ‘good subsets’. It doesn’t contain *all* of the good subsets, but it contains *only* good subsets, which is all that you require.

Comment: Yes, I just need "only" good subsets, not all of them. Great. Thank you once again for your help! Much appreciated!

Comment: @Jules: My pleasure!